# New to Javascript, Color Changes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to Javascript and I cannot figure out how to make this code work. I have an HTML page and a Javascript page. I'm trying to get the buttons to function properly, but I can't even get the color change to work. Where am I going wrong here? Did I not link the files properly?

```
HTML: 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript practice</title>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" 

    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

        <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

        <button id="button1">Grow</button>
        <button id="button2">Blue</button>
        <button id="button3">Fade</button>
        <button id="button4">Reset</button>


    </body>
    </html>

Javascript:


    document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){

        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

})
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript file in the same directory as your HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JavaScript looks for elements with specific `id`s, it can't be run before those elements are actually loaded into memory.

Make sure your JavaScript file is in the same directory as your HTML file (because the way you've linked to it, that's the location it implies) and place the entire `<script>  ... </script>` just before the closing of the `body` tag (`</body>`) so that when the code runs, the elements will have been loaded into memory.

As you can see from the code below, the code will work fine if that switch is made:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript practice</title>
    <!-- It's OK to have your JQuery script reference up here because JQuery isn't 
         going to rely on any of your elements in this document in order to run. -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>

  <!-- For demo purposes, I have the script in the document. But, when the script
       is in another file, place the reference to that file right here, in place
       of the embedded script:
       
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  -->
  <script>
     document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
     });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

FYI: `type=text/javascript` is not needed in HTML5 documents.

Comment: THANK YOU! That helped so much; I got it to work with that. I appreciate you taking the time to answer this!

Answer (score -3):

you need to create active class in style and add that class onClick event using jquery

```js
$('button').on("click",function(){  
  //$('button').not(this).removeClass();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  });
```

```css
.active{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: If you look at the location of the `script` element in the code, you can see that the issue is that the script is executing `document.getElementById()` before the elements are in the DOM.

Comment: Also, your answer refers to an `active` class that is not, in any way, asked about in the question and your answer provides a JQuery solution, but the question was not tagged with JQuery. If you look at the code, you'll be able to see that the JQuery is most likely for the "grow" and "fade" effects.